# best way to highlight text from a website search

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I'd like to create a custom search page for my website. The search page has one textbox on it and a search button. When search results are returned, I'd like to highlight any exact matches.

What's the best way to do the highlighting part? KnockoutJS, jQuery, etc.

Comment: if you can show anything you tried it can be helpful to advice or tweak a bit . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are asking how to highlight something using Knockoutjs. This is what the `css` binding is commonly used for.

```
<input data-bind="text: searchText"></input>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div data-bind="css: { 'highlight': $component.isItemFiltered($data) }">
        <my-item></my-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

`isItemFiltered` would return a boolean indicating whether the item in the loop is currently considered a "match" to the search results.